# Special characters in the extracted text file compressed with tar gzip

Tags: linux, console, tar, gzip

When i create the archive of a text file with this command:

> tar -zcvf file.gz file.txt

and then i extract it get some strange characters in the begin and in the end of file like these:

> \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000644\

How can i remove them? Is it any case to create archive of the one single text file without these special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar cfz` creates a gzipped tar: `file.tar.gz`. It is the same as `tar cf file.tar` followed by `gzip file.tar`.
Extract such a file with `tar xvfz` (or `gunzip file.tar.gz && tar xvf file.tar`, but the `z` is shorter).

For single files use `gzip` and `gunzip` (possibly with `-k` or `--keep` to keep the original file).

Comment: What he's trying to say is that you can't extract it with just gzip. You _made_ it with tar, so you have to _extract_ it with tar. If you incorrectly just use gzip, you will get that tar header with lots of zeros.

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution, thank you, it's need to use gzip this way:
"$gzip -c file.txt > file.gz"